# Remove LineComment in Java AST

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I´m trying to remove a LineComment from a java file via AST. I read the document from a source file, create an AST parser (AST.JLS3) and afterwards create a CompilationUnit and an ASTRewrite instance.

```
doc = new Document( doctext );
parser = ASTParser.newParser( AST.JLS3 );
parser.setSource( doc.get().toCharArray() );
cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST( null );
astRewrite = ASTRewrite.create( cu.getAST() );
```

Nothing special so far, I´m able to add and remove fields a.s.o. Now I´m trying to remove comments from the unit with the following code:

```
@SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
final List<Comment> comments = (List<Comment>) cu.getCommentList();
final Iterator<Comment> commentIter = comments.iterator();
while ( commentIter.hasNext() ) {
  final Comment curComment = commentIter.next();
  if ( curComment.isLineComment() ) {
    final LineComment lineComment = (LineComment) curComment;
    lineComment.accept( new CommentCopyrightFieldVisitor( cu, document.get(), astRewrite ) );
  }
}
```

Here´s the visitor that should perform the action and remove the comment.

```
public class CommentFieldVisitor extends ASTVisitor {

  final CompilationUnit cu;

  final String sourceCode;

  final ASTRewrite astRewrite;

  public CommentFieldVisitor( final CompilationUnit cu, final String sourceCode, final ASTRewrite astRewrite ) {
    this.cu = cu;
    this.sourceCode = sourceCode;
    this.astRewrite = astRewrite;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean visit( final LineComment commentNode ) {
    int start = commentNode.getStartPosition();
    int end = start + commentNode.getLength();
    final String comment = sourceCode.substring( start, end );
    final String fieldComment = Config.INSTANCE.getTargetFieldComment();

    if ( comment != null && comment.equalsIgnoreCase( fieldComment ) ) {
      System.out.println( "REMOVE COMMENT" );
      assert astRewrite != null : "ERROR: AST Rewriter is null";
      astRewrite.remove( commentNode, null );
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

I iterate all comments in the compilation unit, I create a visitor for every comment in the list. This visitor checks, if the content of the comment equals a preconfigured string. If it does, it should be removed. Though if I call

```
astRewrite.remove( commentNode, null );
```

I always get a NPE from inside the remove method. astRewrite and commentNode are defined (because the remove-code is reached.

Does anyone have an idea, what I might be doing wrong? Or another approach how to remove such a comment via AST?

Comment: Not familiar with "Java AST", but if the commentNode is really a node *in* the tree, making it null might damage navigability of the tree?

Comment: ... the docs for astRewrite.remove suggest the second argument must be a TextEditGroup; it doesn't say it can be null.

Answer (score 1):

I managed it via a workaround which uses `Comment.getStartPosition()` and `Comment.getLength()`. I use these methods to exract the comments from my source code file and replace them with "". After that I need to re-create the AST tree from the modified source code. This is far away from perfect, but I didn´t find an alternative solution.

Comment: If all you want is the source text minus the comments, you can run our Java Prettyprinter with -NoComments command line option.  It will read the Java Source and strip all the comments.  See my bio.

Comment: Thank you, I´ll have a look at it...though I only want to remove special comments and replace them. Thus I´ll have to do some kind of extraction and parsing. I´m still wondering why you have to do some kind of hacks to do something like this. There has to be a better way.

Comment: So you really want to replace certain comments?  Your objection is that you didn't really *remove* the comments, all you did was make them null, and then you copied the tree?  (Why couldn't you have copied the tree, dropping the comment nodes as you go? That still seems clumsy).  I could show you the code to do this for a different tool than Java AST, and yes, it is a lot more straightforward.

Comment: As I need to process thousands of java files within my repository, I wanted to avaoid String-regex operations as you never know if your pattern hits all possible versions. Thus I decided to use JDT/AST (now I know that there are better or at least more handy alternatives, but now it´s too late) to have a more generic approach to get everything that looks like a comment. I really remove them using direct string operations on the source code, then I recreate the AST a.s.o. before adding my changed / updated comments. Maybe copying the tree would have been an alternative...I didn´t think of that.

Answer (score 0):

A tiny bit late here but I'm sure the answer will help other people.

I can confirm the NPE with `remove` method when it lacks the required context of a `ICompilationUnit` to execute. This results in :

```
REMOVE COMMENT
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.StructuralPropertyDescriptor.isChildListProperty()" because "property" is null
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.rewrite.ASTRewrite.remove(ASTRewrite.java:398)
```

Here's how I do when I don't have such context:

```java
String sourceCode = "/* block comment */ public class Hello {} // line comment";
Document doc = new Document(sourceCode);
ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.getJLSLatest());
parser.setSource(doc.get().toCharArray());
CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
ASTRewrite astRewrite = ASTRewrite.create(cu.getAST());
TextEdit edits = astRewrite.rewriteAST(doc, null);
final List<Comment> comments = cu.getCommentList();
List<TextEdit> textEdits = new ArrayList<>();
for (Comment curComment : comments) {
    if (curComment.isLineComment()) {
        final LineComment lineComment = (LineComment) curComment;
        int commentStart = lineComment.getStartPosition();
        int commentLength = lineComment.getLength();
        int commentEnd = commentStart + commentLength;
        String comment = sourceCode.substring(commentStart, commentEnd);
        if (comment != null && comment.equalsIgnoreCase("// line comment")) {
            textEdits.add(new DeleteEdit(commentStart, commentLength));
        }
    }
}
edits.addChildren(textEdits.toArray(TextEdit[]::new));
try {
    edits.apply(doc);
    System.out.println(doc.get());
} catch (MalformedTreeException | BadLocationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

See also this project https://github.com/JnRouvignac/AutoRefactor and especially these 2 classes below:

- ASTCommentRewriter.java for the solution above with the list of `DeleteEdit`
- CommentsCleanUp.java for the usage of `ASTRewrite.remove()`